# statistical computing by R

Tags: r

Suppose we have a Gaussian regression model, y_i~N(α+β_1 x_i+β_2 z_i,σ). This model is fitted to the trees data in R where y is Height, x is Girth and z is Volume. 
Following is the result from the simple linear regression:

Call:
lm(formula = Height ~ Girth + Volume)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        Girth       Volume
    83.2958      -1.8615       0.5756

Generate random values for Height based on the model with σ = 5 that corresponds with each pair of values for Girth and Volume.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I think you should add the self-study tag and take a look at the associated wiki page. Also look at ?summary and ?rnorm. Your question title isn't specific enough also.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be in the stack overflow website since its a programming question not a statistics question.

Here is how you would do it in R:

```
data(trees)
m  <- lm(Height~Girth+Volume,data=trees)
mu <- cbind(1,trees$Girth,trees$Volume) %*% m$coef

rnorm(nrow(trees),mu,5)
```